# Having an issue with Javascript spread

Tags: javascript

Consider the two objects:

### obj1

```js
{
   myObj: {
      key1: "value1",
      key2: "value2"
   }
}
```

### obj2

```js
{
   myObj: {
      key2: "new_value2",
      key3: "value3",
   }
}
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```js
let combined = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

The intended output is:

```js
{
   myObj: {
      key1: "value1",
      key2: "new_value2",
      key3: "value3"
   }
}
```

However, what I'm getting is:

```js
{
   myObj: {
      key2: "new_value2",
      key3: "value3"
   }
}
```

It's essentially overwriting `obj1`, not merging them.

How do I merge and overwrite?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible with spread like that. You are going to have to write something recursive or define the myObj and spread inside of that.

Comment: `let combined = { myObj: {...obj1.myObj, ...obj2.myObj }};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use spread operator like below.

```
let combined = {myObj: {...obj1.myObj, ...obj2.myObj}}
```

Comment: *distruct* ????

Answer (score 1):

Obj1 and Obj2 have a nested Object called myObj, to be able to use the value within myObj you need to refer to the correct Object using

```
obj1.myObj
```

and

```
obj2.myObj
```

The final result would look like

```
let combined = {myObj: {...obj1.myObj, ...obj2.myObj}}
```